# How do I merge cells in Excel with VBA with hundreds of data set

Tags: excel, vba

Original data looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaJav.jpg)

I want to make the VBA code below to replicate hundreds of time for hundreds of data set

`Sub mergeCellsAndCenter()

```
   With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:C6")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
     End With

     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D5:D6")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
     End With

     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5:E6")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
     End With


    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C7:C8")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
     End With

     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D7:D8")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
     End With

     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E7:E8")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
     End With

     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C9:C10")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge 
     End With

     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D9:D10")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
     End With

     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E9:E10")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Merge
     End With
```

End Sub`
When I run this macro it works for the 10 rows. I want to make it work for hundreds of rows without to have to type each set code."

Comment: Why do you want to merge them with the blank row? Would just deleting the blank row work instead?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you find yourself writing repetitive code there is a high chance you are missing the chance to implement a loop. Lucky you, that is the case here.

Loop through your rows (with a interval of 2) and merge your values for each of your 3 columns individually. It is also best to wait to format your cells until your loop is done. No need to repeat the same operation inside the loop, *which may prove to be time consuming*, when you can format the entire range all at once when you are done with the loop.

---

```
Sub Shelter_In_Place()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 5 To lr Step 2
        ws.Range("C" & i).Resize(2).Merge
        ws.Range("D" & i).Resize(2).Merge
        ws.Range("E" & i).Resize(2).Merge
    Next i

    With ws.Range("C5:E" & lr)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdationg = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the link.  Those look like blank rows, based on what I'm seeing.  My eyes are NOT great, but it looks like blanks to me.  If you want to delete all blank rows in your used range, just run the script below.

```
Public Sub DeleteBlankRows()
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim EntireRow As Range

    Set SourceRange = Application.Selection

    If Not (SourceRange Is Nothing) Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        For I = SourceRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set EntireRow = SourceRange.Cells(I, 1).EntireRow
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(EntireRow) = 0 Then
                EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working. Thank you very much.

@ ASH, thank you for your input even though that was not the request.

The merging of the cells with the blank cells below each one row is simply applied to the Columns B to E and starting with row #05 and looping to finish the cells with values. The Columns F to H will contain drop-downs list (rows 5 and 6) with values related to the set of data in Column B to C as well illustrated by Urdearboy.

Again thank you everyone.